# Save data to a new Workbook with office.js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

Using office.js, is there a way to create a new workbook and then edit the new workbook?

I thought about these two options but couldn't find a way to implement any of them:

- (preferred): Get an object reference when creating the new workbook via Excel.createWorkbook(), similar to VBA, like

```
var newWorkbook = Excel.createWorkbook();
newWorkbook.doStuff();
```

- Create the data in a new Worksheet within the source Workbook and then save this Worksheet as a new Workbook

Comment: You could use [Excel.createWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview#excel-createworkbook-base64-) to create a new Workbook with data in base64 format.

Comment: @DongqiLv thanks for your comment. But how would I create the base64 data from the source workboook?

Comment: There's common API to get the base64-encoded string, this reference page could help: [Create a workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook)

Comment: @DongqiLv thanks, but I understand that you can only copy the entire workbook, not a specific worksheet. And there is still no way to edit the new workbook directly right?